# use bootstrap and material-UI both together in a project

Tags: bootstrap-4, material-ui, react-bootstrap

if I use bootstrap and material-UI both together in a  project, then is it will any impact on my website or web application?
Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The boostrap material UI css and bootstrap.min.css have conflict styles in terms of font-size and grid alignment.

But the effect is not much, and you can still use it in your projects. For instance, I used both bootstrap and material UI for this site [www.fischela.com](http://www.fischela.com), and it works pretty fine.

Comment: yes, we can use both of them in any project,
but is it will not slow down our web app due to the use of both powerful libraries together in a project?